# Как исправить ошибку при сборке в android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Что делать если вылазит такая ошибка в файле **Application.mk** присутствует запись `APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64` если написать так `APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a x86` то ошибка все ровно остается!

> Build command failed.
>
> Error while executing process
>   C:\Users\pavel\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with
>   arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null
>   APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\android-project\app\jni\Android.mk
>   NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\android-project\app\jni\Application.mk
>   APP_ABI=armeabi NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi NDK_DEBUG=1
>   APP_PLATFORM=android-14
>   NDK_OUT=D:/android-project/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj
>   NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\android-project\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib
>   APP_PLATFORM=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false
>   LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>
> Android NDK: INTERNAL ERROR: The armeabi ABI should have exactly one
>   architecture definitions. Found: ''
>
> process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>
> *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop. Open File
>
> Build command failed.
>
> Error while executing process
>   C:\Users\pavel\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with
>   arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null
>   APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\android-project\app\jni\Android.mk
>   NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\android-project\app\jni\Application.mk
>   APP_ABI=armeabi NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi NDK_DEBUG=0
>   APP_PLATFORM=android-14
>   NDK_OUT=D:/android-project/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj
>   NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\android-project\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\release\lib
>   APP_PLATFORM=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false
>   LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>
> Android NDK: INTERNAL ERROR: The armeabi ABI should have exactly one
>   architecture definitions. Found: ''
>
> process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>
> *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop. Open File

Comment: Версии AS & NDK в студию.

Comment: 17.14828580 <- NDK , Android Studio 3.1.4